# whats the proper use of z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Is there a way that I could make div "subSect" overstack the text on div "red"? I've been searching for hours but I can't seem to find a answer. I'm using z-index but nothing is really working. I'm sure I'm missing something.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body{
 height: 100%;
}

.sectOne{
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(images/idea.jpg);
}

.red{
 font-size: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
}

.subSect{
 height: 70%;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Parallax</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="red">
 <p>sample</p>
</div>

<div class="sect sectOne"></div>

<div class="subSect"></div>

<div style="height: 1000px"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your z-index in .subSect is lower that .red, That's all in this case.

Answer (score 1):

your `z-index` in `.subSect` is lower that .`red`, If I understand correctly you don't want to be able to select the text in `.red`, so for that set a negative `z-index`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.sectOne {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/900/900);
}
.red {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.subSect {
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
    <p>sample</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sect sectOne"></div>

  <div class="subSect">asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd </div>

  <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number one rule about `z-index` is that once you start with them, you'll end up using many.

This mostly happens because web developers do not fully understand the mechanics behind them, especially the concept of *stacking contexts*.

A *stacking context* is the container in which the `z-index` does its deed, a `z-index` will never break out of its *stacking context*, though you can influence the z-ordering of *stacking contexts* themselves of course.

From [the MDN article on *stacking contexts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), this is the summary of what exactly creates a *stacking context*, some of them are known to the majority of web developers (e.g. `position: absolute`), while others are not (e.g. `opacity: 0.999`).

- Positioning and assigning a z-index value to an HTML element creates
  a stacking context, (as does assigning non-full opacity).
- Stacking contexts can be contained in other stacking contexts, and 
  together create a hierarchy of stacking contexts.
- Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: 
  only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.
- Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents 
  are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of 
  the parent stacking context.

In your example the power at play against the intended z-ordering is that the elements you are trying to influence are both within the same *stacking context* (`<html>` is the first and foremost *stacking context*, always there) and the z-indices or both `.red` (`z-index: 100`) and `.sectOne` (`z-index: 50`) are simply in the wrong order.

In fact, if you were to drop the meddling with `z-index` completely, the "natural order" of the HTML syntax in itself is more than willing to do exactly what you (seem to) want, to show the contents of `.sectOne` over the fixed positioned `.red`.

```
.red {
    font-size: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}

.subSect {
  height: 70%;
  position: relative;
  /* provide some coloring to see what is going on */
  background-color: #ff0; 
}
```

[A working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxdnqsg4/) to demonstrate this.

All I did what provide some visual aid to show that - indeed - `.sectOne` is over `.red`.

That is for the question at hand, one can deduce from that question, the given HTML and the fact that you started tampering with `z-index` at all, that you'd want several blocks of content under and over the fixed element, for this it should suffice to provide some *stacking context*-trigger on the elements you want on top and not on the elements that should pass underneath.

[A working fiddle to demonstrate this](https://jsfiddle.net/0pprje35/).